# string indices error while creating customize dictionary from data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to create dictionary from dataframe and below is data frame and code:

```
Code | Desc
XS   | Train
XS   | Car
SE   | Cycle
SE   | Train
```

And below is the my code

```
lst_code = 'NA'
comp_list=[]
comp_dict = {}
for row in test_df:
    if str(row['code']) != lst_code:
        lst_code = row['code']
        if comp_list:
            comp_dict.update(lst_code,comp_list)
    else:
        comp_list.append(row['desc'])
```

Using above code I am getting below error

```
if str(row['analyst_code']) != lst_code:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am expecting below dictionary :

```
comp_dict = {'XS':['Train','Car'],
          'SE':['Cycle','Train']}
```

Please suggest, how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then count per groups by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), last convert `Series` [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
lst_code = 'NA'
comp_dict = df[df['Code'] != lst_code].groupby('Code')['Desc'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (comp_dict)
{'SE': ['Cycle', 'Train'], 'XS': ['Train', 'Car']}
```

If not necessary filtering:

```
comp_dict = df.groupby('code')['Desc'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Comment: Hi @Jezrael given dataframe is smaple actually I have many rows of data where should I put your line of code in the loop Or separately? Could you please advice.

Comment: @RajeshMhatre - Not sure if understand, but my code is instead your (I hope it return same output with real data)

Comment: I tried your code but it says `name 'lst_code' is not defined` where to assign value for lst_code ?

Comment: @RajeshMhatre - btw, if want filter missing values, better is use `df.dropna(subset=['Code'])`

Comment: Hey, @Jezrael thanks I got it , lst_code was created just because I was looping it. In your code it is not required. So final answer will be `comp_dict = df.groupby('code')['Desc'].apply(list).to_dict()`